# C#Switch statement with a combo box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

currently i'm attempting to using a switch statement to change between time zone with a project for school.

```
if (extTime1.timeZone == "CDT")
{
   switch (cboTimeZone.SelectedItem.ToString)
   {
      case "EST":
      time1.Hour = time1.Hour + 1; /* CDT hours + 1 to get EST */
      extTime1.Hour = extTime1.Hour + 1;
      break;

      case "MST":
      time1.Hour = time1.Hour - 1; /* CDT hours - 1 to get MST */
      break;

      case "PST":
      time1.Hour = time1.Hour - 2; /* CDT hours - 2 to get PST */
      break;

      default: /* CDT is the default time zone*/
      break;
  }

}
```

I can't seem to get the cboTimeZone to work correctly. I always thought SelectedItem was the correct choice in this situation. Apparently not?

Comment: SelectedItem would be correct if this were databound. I'm guessing you just have a list of combobox items defined in the aspx file right?

Comment: What is the object type for the Item in your collection for the combobox?

Comment: SelectedIndex works buut it says it can't convert the values to int? >> Weird. I just defined the list via the gui (click the item then the little arrow etc etc you know the drill) 
object type for the item? It's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .Text.  The asp.net ajax combobox is actually a combination of a textbox and dropdownlist, which implements the ITextControl interface.

Answer (score 0):

Let me look at this:

```
if (extTime1.timeZone == "CDT")
{
   // Try this
   string text = cboTimeZone.SelectedItem.ToString(); // don't forget the parenthesis
   MessageBox.Show(text, "Debug");
   // Then this
   text = cboTimeZone.Text;
   MessageBox.Show(text, "Debug");
   // then (as a safeguard)
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
   {
       return;
   }
   switch (text)
   {
      case "EST":
      time1.Hour = time1.Hour + 1; /* CDT hours + 1 to get EST */
      extTime1.Hour = extTime1.Hour + 1;
      break;

      case "MST":
      time1.Hour = time1.Hour - 1; /* CDT hours - 1 to get MST */
      break;

      case "PST":
      time1.Hour = time1.Hour - 2; /* CDT hours - 2 to get PST */
      break;

      default: /* CDT is the default time zone*/
      break;
  }

}
```